# How to read a document into a string using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to read a document into a string using python

```
all = [f for f in os.listdir(dirname)]
for f in all:
    documents+=1
    with open(dirname+'/'+f, 'r') as myfile:
        alldocs.append(f)
        data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '') 
        for token in data.split():
            alltokens.append(token)
            tokens+=1
```

I am receiving the following error when I execute my code  with

```
open(dirname+'/'+f, 'r') as myfile:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
```

Any guidance on where I might be going wrong will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you executing the script with the sufficient permissions?

Comment: You don't have proper permissions?

Comment: Yes I just realised that I  probably shouldnt try to access the root directiory, what directory should I try to access or should create a new directory ( if so how do I implement that) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have permission for that path,
try to run the script with a user that has permission or check the full path that `os.listdir` returns.